# Arduino board Power Polarity

Tags: arduino, power-supply

I don't know if the power plug should have `+` at the inner contact or the outer.

Comment: take an ohmmeter and measure between something clearly marked as ground on the board (if anything).  Perhaps large mounting holes if they have a metal ring.

Comment: please add your "solution" as an answer. Also, quoting some of that content in your answer or summarizing it would not only make the your answer more valuable in the event that Arduino changed their URL structure or removed that page, it would make it quicker and easier for readers to decide if they wanted to click that link.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer: I added an answer [below](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/arduino-board-power-polarity/14701#14701)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

positive is in the center of the plug.  This is a pretty typical way to do it, because having positive on the outside is just inviting shorts if you pull the plug, and then drop it on something that's grounded.

Comment: I just looked it up to be safe :) http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1138892708

Answer (score 2):

A good documentation on the official Arduino Wiki: [arduino.cc/playground/Learning/WhatAdapter](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Learning/WhatAdapter)

+ is the center contact
- is the outer contact

```
         .---.
 -  ----<  O----  +
         `---´
```

- DC should be between 9V and 12V (20V max)
- It's a 2.1mm power plug